# Pass data from react component

Tags: javascript, database, reactjs

I have a GetData.js component that gets API data and sets it to an array. I want to access that array data in multiple other components and manipulate it in multiple different ways.

For example, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
import APIdata from './GetData';

var data = APIdata.object;

var result = [];

if (data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data.form_values["6f71"] === "KeyWord") {
      result.push(data)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can wrap that data in a parent Component and pass it down as a property when  needed.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate how i would do that? Sorry, i am new to react.@LaneTerry

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at a fairly straightforward use of container components, props, and state.

Here's a contrived example:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import OtherComponent1 from './OtherComponent1';
import OtherComponent2 from './OtherComponent2';

class GetDataComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }

  fetchMyData() {
    const resultingArray = ...
    this.setState({data: resultingArray});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchMyData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <OtherComponent1 someArrayProp={this.state.data}/>
        <OtherComponent2 differentArrayProp={this.state.data}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class OtherComponent1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        The someArrayProp: {this.props.someArrayProp}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

OtherComponent1.propTypes = {
  someArrayProp: PropTypes.array;
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const OtherComponent2 = (props) => (
  <div>
    The differentArrayProp: {props.differentArrayProp}
  </div>
);

OtherComponent2.propTypes = {
  differentArrayProp: PropTypes.array;
}

export default App;
```